# Rails 3.2 params in render action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, render

I want to pass parameters to a view from a controller via render action. I tried the following but its not working.

```
 render action: "new",:from=> "publish_page", id: 233
```

If you have any idea please share. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set your params in controller:

```
params[:from] = 'publish_page'
params[:id] = 233
render :new
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are allowed, nor supposed to do this.

Params should be considered in the controller. Either `redirect` if you want to access a URL with specific params or use instance variables if you want to communicate something to your views.